# How to make graph from array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, graph

I would like to make a graph using a known array. The following code is working:

```
 Sub arraychart()
  Dim cht As Object
  Dim hhh As Variant

 Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=300, Top:=10, Height:=300)
 With cht

 .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1:d29")
 .Chart.Type = xlLine
 .Left = 350
 .Width = 400
 .Top = 30
 .Height = 200

 End With
 End Sub
```

But I want to use a array array1= Sheets("Data").Range("a1:d29") instead of

```
  .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1:d29")
```

How could i code this? Thanks!

Comment: Amir have you had a chance to try the solution I posted?

Comment: The title is confusing. It should be (...) from Range, not from array, wich in VBA is a bit different.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use the individual components of the `Series` object. The `SetSourceData` method requires a range, and cannot use a Variant array.

Below example assumes  X-values (category labels) in column A, and three series of data in columns B, C and D.  Modify as needed.

```
Sub arraychart()
Dim cht As Object
Dim hhh As Variant
Dim srs as Series
Dim arrayValues as Variant
Dim arrayXValues as Variant
Dim rng as Range
Dim c as Integer

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=300, Top:=10, Height:=300)

'Define the range you'll use:
Set rng = Range("A1:D29") 'modify as needed

'Define the array of X-Values to use in the chart
arrayXValues = rng.Columns(1).Value

With cht
     .Chart.Type = xlLine
     .Left = 350
     .Width = 400
     .Top = 30
     .Height = 200
     'Create each series in the chart
     For c = 2 to rng.Columns.Count
         'Define the array of values for each series
         arrayValues = rng.Columns(c).Value
         Set srs = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         With srs
             .XValues = arrayXValues
             .Values = arrayValues
             .Name = "whatever you want to name it, etc." 'Modify as needed
         End With
     Next

End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

Here's an example chart from example data:

[image]

**NOTE** The only time I've ever done this was due to some corporate directive that our graphics application was supposed to produce charts which cannot easily (or mistakenly) be modified by users or consumers.  So we spent a long time building, developing, and supporting this approach.

It makes the "data" independent of the sheet/calculation/etc. While this has some uses, like it prevents users from inadvertently "breaking" the chart, it also makes it hard or impossible for the average user to update or modify the chart *intentionally*.

And, it goes against everything users expect about charts, you can't use them to easily visualize changes in the data, you can't easily modify them by adding new series, or removing existing series on the Worksheet, etc.  There are probably other reasons to hate this approach...

In short, I would not recommend doing it this way unless your paycheck depends on it.  Ultimately, they asked us to go back to "normal" charts using the `SetSourceData` or `Series.Formula` methods.

Comment: `... Set srs = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries ...` It should be without `.Chart` just `Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries`

Comment: @rafaBG it's been two years since I looked at that but I'm pretty sure that I tested at the time since I also provided screenshot of its output. ..